# Graph Remove Edge Number Independent Sets Size 5

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, expectation

I am unsure of how to do this problem.

Define a random graph $G=(V,E)$ as follows. The vertex set of $G$ is $V=\left\{1,...,n\right\}$. Now for
each pair $\left\{i,j\right\}$ with $i ≠ j ∈ [n]$, add the pair $\left\{i,j\right\}$ to $E$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ independent of the choice for every other pair. Let $X_5$ be the $\#$ of independent sets of size $5$ in the graph $G$. Compute the expectation of $X_5$. (Note: an independent set is a set of vertices $I$ in $G$ such that no two vertices in $I$ have an edge between them).

Also, for future reference, what is a good way of approaching these expectational problems? Anyway, my theory on how to solve this problem was to compute the expected value of getting just 1 independent set of size $5$ and then summing it up for all n nodes or something like that. The problem is, I'm not sure how to calculate the probability of getting an independent set either and what to do afterwards.

Comment: For a given set $S$ of $5$ vertices, the probability that $S$ is independent is $(\frac12)^{\binom52},$ and the number of such sets is $\binom n5,$ so the expectation is $$E(X_5)=\frac{\binom n5}{2^{\binom52}}=\frac{\binom n5}{1024}.$$

Comment: In other words, you want to calculate the probability that a **given** set of $5$ vertices is independent, and sum that over all **$5$-element sets** of vertices.

Comment: @Y. Lou, please, read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you @bof for helping me. For future reference, what's a good way of approaching these kinds of expectation problems?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment because of reputation.

A good way to tackle expectation problems is to keep in mind that expectation is linear, i.e. $$\sum_i E[X_i] = E\big[\sum_i X_i\big]$$ for any random variables $X_i$, *no independence needed*.

So as long as you if you have identical subproblems that you can solve, you're done.